# libGDX android assets file not found

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm testing my app (with android, core and desktop modules) on desktop, everything works fine.

Now that I try to run on Android, it gives me FileNotFound. I linked android asset to desktopLauncher before running on desktop, but Am I meant to do something similar for android?

```
            File file = Gdx.files.internal("liver_initial_joints.json").file();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fis.read(data);
            fis.close();

            str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

I have my file at .../android/assets/liver_initial_joints.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not provide direct java.io.File access to the internal app directory. If you look at the javadocs for libgdx's `FileHandle.file()`, you'll see that it says it's not usable for anything but Absolute and External types of files.

If you just need to read a string or byte array, you can use `fileHandle.readString()` or `fileHandle.readBytes()`. If you need an input stream, use `fileHandle.read();`.

For example:

```
        byte[] data = Gdx.files.internal("liver_initial_joints.json").read();
        str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: internal().read() returns an inputStream instead of byte[].
But it's a solution and it worked, I just had to call internal().read().read(data).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I find a really easy way to do this is with:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("liver_initial_joints.json");
```

Comment: Thanks!
But, is this platform specific code? is 'context' the android SDK Context ?